# Visual Studio Extension, adding an additional context-menu action when right-clicking on a nuget package added as a reference in project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions

I am currently learning how to create extension for visual studio but I have an issue targeting a specific location in VS.

I've created a command and by default it add correctly the button action to the tool bar.

The place where I would want to add an option is here : (Only on NuGet package added as a reference)
[image]

I'll probably need to add specific code to target this in my command.cs, but not sure how to attack the problem.

I tried to look in Tools > Customize but even there can't seem to be able to find the reference to it.

I've tried to look online for the VS group ID so I can refer to it as a group but couldn't find it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I tested each context menu in the customize selection of the selection "Tools" in the top menu.

However, I found the context menu related to reference not make the part you mentioned change(I changed those context menu, but the performance didn't change).

Based on my research, because of the substantial items, the official document doesn't offer desription about them.

But there should have another way to check the command definition and it's GUID:

[To locate a command definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/guids-and-ids-of-visual-studio-commands?view=vs-2022#to-locate-a-command-definition)

The path on my side:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Inc
```

Comment: Hi @Bowman Zhu-MSFT, Thanks a lot. I'll keep digging and post the answer if I find it.

Comment: @Rekasi Hi Rekasi, have you found it? :)

Comment: Hey, sadly no. I spent a lot of time trying to find how to do it but couldn't find the solution so I put it on Ice for the moment. The GUID doesn't seem to exist. I will probably have to do another session of learning MS extension to do something custom.